# 'Suffer' word etymology from Arabic ‎صفر‎ doubt?

Tags: etymology

'Suffer' word etymology from Arabic ‎صفر‎ (safar: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safar)  which is the name of a month of suffering has any relation?

Comment: I doubt most people here can read Arabic, so not many are likely to know what you even wrote. But no, ‘suffer’ does not come from Arabic. It is Latin, from _sufferre_ ‘to undergo’, composed of _sub_ ‘under’ and _ferre_ ‘carry, bear’. This is General Reference.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I think you should post your comment as an answer, as well.

Comment: @Boluc its upto 13th century Latin but what before that?

Comment: As far as I can tell Safar comes from the same roots as zero, number,etc. A word in English that comes from this root is cipher. Suffer is derived from another root, as Janus stated. I am pretty confident that the latin root of suffer was used before the implementation of the Islamic Calendar.

Comment: @Boluc Safar was used long ago before zero Sifr came.

Comment: @ put on hold staff. You don't know the answer doesn't mean you should close the question.

Answer (score 1):

No relation at all. ‘Suffer’ is derived from Latin. صفر‎ may be a month of suffering, but the nearest the verb seems to get to ‘suffer’ is, in the form ‘safira’, ‘to be empty, be devoid, vacant’, according to Hans Wehr’s ‘Dictionary of Modern Literary Arabic’. And ص, of course, is not the same letter as the English ‘s’.

Comment: Could the 13c suffer not have etymology from much earlier Arabic?

Comment: does'nt matter  ‎‏ ‏صsound is like 's' as like in cipher.

Comment: @ mplungjan. Unlikely, I’d have thought, given that Latin ‘suffere’ is in turn made up of the prefix ‘sub’ and the verb ‘ferre’.

Answer (score -3):

yeah it does and it doesn't the people used to call this month as safar cause they suffer in this month 
Literal meaning: Empty. During this month the houses used to be empty and deserted because the ban on going to war in the month of Muharram came to an end and everyone proceeded towards the battlefield.
Safar also means to be yellow. When the names of the months were being given it was the season of autumn and the leaves of the trees were yellow.

Comment: without source? Its nonsense.

Comment: Cut and paste from a questionable article from Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safar

Comment: Yeah it is copy pasted to show you the source but , there is no relation in between the Latin derived  word Suffer and the month name called Safar, As though Safar also means travelling because  in these days people use to travel for battlefield

Comment: @waqar first of all the islamic month safar is not a suffering month and second that latin word sifar  is not derived from arabic and also there is no relation in between because  Latin emerged as a language around 1000 B.C. okay the source is here wikipedia 
Dizionario Etimologico Italiano 
7 years of Latin 
Italian native speaker who speaks spanish and is studying Arabic.